# Mac operating system from disc at startup

Tags: startup, unix, bootable-disk

Hello everyone and thank you in advance.

I have just downloaded Linux Ubuntu and put it on a disk. What i want to do is to hold C during the Mac startup so that I can choose to boot my mac through the CD with the Linux Ubuntu operating system. However, I am worried about what will happen when I run my Mac through this CD and I have some questions

1. How do I change back between operating systems?
2. Will the startup commands work the same?
3. What will happen if I turn my computer off and eject the disk? Will
   my Mac just launch normally?
4. Any other information about booting from a disk that may be relevant

I understand this might seem stupid but please answer if you have any idea of how this whole "boot through CD thing works"! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Just press Alt/Optn on startup.
2. Absolutely
3. Yes
4. There is noting special, [read here on other bootup options](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1533)